# Codename One converting String to JSON object

Tags: json, codenameone

How do you convert this string to JSON data in codenameone.

```
{result_code=0.0, data=[{id=1007747505, name=Test, dob=1986-05-16, identification=6837904, otherinformation=, status=Active, classid=11, class=Twenty, start_date=2016-05-27, end_date=2017-05-26}], message=OK}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `JSONParser` class as described in the [developer guide](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/files-storage-networking.html) using:

```
JSONParser p = new JSONParser();
Map<String, Object> results = p.parseJSON(new CharArrayReader("{result_code=0.0, data=[{id=1007747505, name=Test, dob=1986-05-16, identification=6837904, otherinformation=, status=Active, classid=11, class=Twenty, start_date=2016-05-27, end_date=2017-05-26}], message=OK}".toCharArray());
```

The trick is to place a breakpoint after that line and look at the contents of "results" to see the data structure returned by the parser.